# spring concurrency how spring handles multiple requests at the same time

Tags: concurrency

Suppose if 1000 requests are sent to the browser at the same time by 1000 different users, how spring serves each request. As spring bean default scope uhh s singleton how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good question - You can use `scope="prototype"` for each of your controller bean ,which will make your Bean essentially NON SINGLETON...  but do keep in mind `"NOT" to have instance variable defined`. I have faced situation in past where even though I kept the scope=prototype my instance variables were shared between various user session.

```
Stick to Immutiblity
```